# Ways of saying "out of breath" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, choix-de-mot

What are the differences between *être essoufflé, être hors d'haleine,* and *être à bout de souffle* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... in short :

*essoufflé* : (you can hardly breathe) < *hors d'haleine* (you cannot breathe) < *à bout de souffle*... hmmm... it sounds like... the... end! ;)

Hey wait! It only sounds like...

Because...

Next step is *à son dernier souffle*. That is... actually... the end! ;)